# Stand alone sleek application for Windows - But I'm python/Java dev. What is the least learning curve way?

Tags: windows, silverlight, prism, py2exe

The application is simple and deals with showing images and simple image manipulation.

I know python and java, but haven't seen a sleek standalone application built in them on windows. I'm not sure how reliable py2exe is.

Going the .Net/C# seems to be the only way, which I dread, since I've never done any programming in those.

Is there another way ? I've heard about silverlight & prism. Don't know if they can access filesystems when you make a standalone application out of them.

Comment: if you know java why does c# scare you?

Comment: Linking this dll to that one and I haven't worked in C.. Maybe the fear in unfounded and you are correct..

Answer (score 0):

Since you know Python maybe [IronPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) is an option for you? You can also use create a Swing Java app

Answer (score -1):

It's a little fringe right now - but you can use the new Python tools for VS 2010
http://pytools.codeplex.com/

If you don't have VS, download the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) Redistributable Package" http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e5aa7b6-8436-43f0-b778-00c3bca733d3&displaylang=en

then you can install the python tools...

Keep in mind you'll still have to learn XAML or WinForms & it's still .net...

Hope the helps.